# Blank screen on boot with no errors and disk issue

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, fstab, disk

Been working on this issue for three hours with no luck. Will have to post images as the laptop is down.

I could not get to the login screen. Just a blank screen. I was getting an error message about bluetooth. Fixed that. No change. Went into recovery and saw it was not finding a disk. Looked in the /etc/fstab and checked against blkid. The id of one drive listed in fstab was not listed in blkid.

This drive was mounted at /media/d/data.

I changed the uid of this disk to my primary Linux filesystem one.

Now I realised that the /media/d/data disk was probably a  external disk that has been accidentaly writted to fstab.

I have two disks for Linux and Windows. The Linux home is encrypted.

Anyone able to make any sense of this? Below are images of the fstab file and blkid output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is absolutely no information to tell anything. Is the question related to Ubuntu in any way?

Comment: Its Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: If your computer boots but just doesn't show the login screen, try using `ctrl` + `alt` + `f2` to get to a terminal, then log in from there. From here, try running `sudo service gdm restart` and post the output of `sudo service gdm status` if there's error.

Comment: I just ran into this issue with a brand new Ubuntu 22.04 install. Mine is also encrypted;  when I get to the blank screen, if I type in the password I set up for the encrypted volume and hit enter then the operating system proceeds to boot up normally. I suspect that the decryption prompt interface is somehow not displaying correctly